# Convert text files to SequentialFileOutput format

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to convert Text files to `sequentialFileoutputFormat` format, but I have an error message:

> java.io.IOException wrong key class /home/mmrao/test.txt is not class
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.LogWritable

```
Mapper 
public class SequenceFi[enter image description here][1]leMapper extends Mapper<NullWritable, BytesWritable, Text, BytesWritable> {
    private Text filenameKey;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        InputSplit split = context.getInputSplit();

        Path path = ((FileSplit) split).getPath();
        // filenameKey = new LongWritable();
        filenameKey = new Text(path.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(NullWritable key, BytesWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(filenameKey, value);
    }
}


WholeFileInputFormat:
public class WholeFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {
    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WholeFileRecordReader reader = new WholeFileRecordReader();
        reader.initialize(split, context);
        return reader;
    }
}

WholeFileRecordReader::

public class WholeFileRecordReader extends RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {
    private FileSplit fileSplit;
    private Configuration conf;
    private BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
    private boolean processed = false;

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        this.fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;
        this.conf = context.getConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (!processed) {
            byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
            Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
            FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
            FSDataInputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = fs.open(file);
                IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
                value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeStream(in);
            }
            processed = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public NullWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return NullWritable.get();
    }

    @Override
    public BytesWritable getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        return processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // do nothing
    }
}

DriverClass:

public class SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter extends Configured implements Tool {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter(), args));
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJobName("SequenceFile ");
        job.setJarByClass(SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        job.setInputFormatClass(WholeFileInputFormat.class);
        // job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(SequenceFileMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);
        // job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        // job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.submit();
        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note: Input files are in Hdfs location giving in command line input and output

Query:

```
hadoop jar seq.jar package.driverclass ip op
```

Eroor Log::::::::::::::::::::

```
mmrao@master:~$ yarn jar /home/mmrao/Downloads/seq.jar seq.SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter /seq/files /seqout

    16/06/25 10:08:43 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
    16/06/25 10:08:45 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
    16/06/25 10:08:45 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
    16/06/25 10:08:46 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1466829146657_0001
    16/06/25 10:08:47 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1466829146657_0001
    16/06/25 10:08:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1466829146657_0001/
    16/06/25 10:08:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1466829146657_0001
    16/06/25 10:08:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1466829146657_0001 running in uber mode : false
    16/06/25 10:08:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    16/06/25 10:09:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
    16/06/25 10:09:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
    16/06/25 10:09:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1466829146657_0001_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    Error: java.io.IOException: wrong key class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.append(SequenceFile.java:1308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat$1.write(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Comment: At what line does it happen? You might need to reduce the code a little, you've put a lot there. [Please read here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to provide a more detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing mistake in writing query. If you can provide exact query then I can give you more certain Answer.

However according to your error it should be due to incorrect query.

Your query should be like this
hadoop jar

Example --> hadoop jar /home/training/Desktop/file.jar DriverFile 
/user/file/abc.txt /user/file/output

Here,
DriverFile --> this is my java class containing main method

/home/training/Desktop/file.jar --> jar-location

/user/file/abc.txt -->full-address-of-file-to-process(this file should be in your hdfs)

/user/file/output  --> output-directory(it should be unique)

if still you have error after applying this. Please take screenshot of your log and post it here

Comment: Yes Siddhartha jain, i givn absolute path to jar as well as the input and output paths ..Please look into this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
This is Error Log for the Question ::::

mmrao@master:~$ yarn jar /home/mmrao/Downloads/seq.jar seq.SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter /seq/files /seqout
16/06/25 10:08:43 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/06/25 10:08:45 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
16/06/25 10:08:45 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/06/25 10:08:46 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1466829146657_0001
16/06/25 10:08:47 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1466829146657_0001
16/06/25 10:08:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1466829146657_0001/
16/06/25 10:08:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1466829146657_0001
16/06/25 10:08:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1466829146657_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/06/25 10:08:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/06/25 10:09:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
16/06/25 10:09:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/06/25 10:09:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1466829146657_0001_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: wrong key class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.append(SequenceFile.java:1308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat$1.write(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```